How to use onclick event (jqueryui-selectable)?
When clicked,
selected: function(event, ui) {
    if (!$(ui.selected).hasClass('selected')) {  
        $(ui.selected).addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(ui.selected).removeClass("ui-selected selected");
    }
}

I want to call the function I defined after the code is executed.
selected: function(event, ui) {
    if (!$(ui.selected).hasClass('selected')) {  
        $(ui.selected).addClass('selected');
    else {
        $(ui.selected).removeClass("ui-selected selected");
    }
    makeGrid();
}

When a calendar date is selected, the date cell changes color and I want makeGrid(); to be executed. makeGrid(); is executed, but the color of the selected date does not change.

Please click [edit] then the button marked [<>] and create a [mcve] with relevant HTML, CSS , JS and frameworks from CDN

You have a syntax error in your second code before else (one } is missing). also please create a minimal reproducible example, so that we can help you properly.
